# XC16 compiler - Inline assembly constraint to create memory operand for BTSTS (indirect memory addressing)

Tags: c, memory, inline-assembly, xc16

What I'm trying to create is a c high level method for calling BTSTS instruction.

What I tried so far:

```
volatile unsigned int a = 1;
asm volatile(
    "btsts %0, #2\n"
    : "+d" (b)
    : 
    : "cc"
);
```

Above produces following assembly output:

```
mov #1,w0
mov w0,[w14]
mov [w14],w0
mov w0,w1

btsts   w1, #2

mov w1,w0
mov w0,[w14]
```

But this is not what I want. The bit should be set directly in memory so that the instruction is atomic:

```
btsts   [w0], #2
```

What is the correct to way to accomplish it?

The nearest approach was following:

*Here "a" is a global variable instead of a local variable*

```
asm volatile(
    "btsts [%0], #2\n"
    :
    : "d" (&a)
    : "cc"
);
```

Following assembly output is generated this time:

```
mov _a,w0
mov w0,w1
btsts [w1], #2
```

It is a bit better, however I don't want to explicitly specify the braces [%0] around it. **Isn't there a way that the compiler/assembler will know that indirect memory addressing is wanted?**

**Edit: I tried one more thing. Despite the fact that "m" constraint was no mentioned in the documentation I tried it**

```
volatile unsigned int r = 0;
void test(volatile unsigned int* t) {
       asm (
       "btsts %0, #2\n"
       : "+m" (t)
   );
}
```

Above will produce something like

```
mov #_r,w0 
...
mov w0,[w14]
btsts [w14], #2
```

This is also incorrect and will not change `r`. Maybe "m" constraint is not mentioned because it is buggy?

Btw. correct code would be

```
btsts [w0], #2
```

or something like

```
mov w0,[w14]
mov [w14],w1
btsts [w1], #2
```

Comment: Your first example shows `"+d" (b)`, but there is no variable named `b` (did you mean `a`?).  I'm not familiar with xc16, but if this were gcc, I'd use `+m` instead of `+d`.  Does xc16 not support this constraint?

Comment: Concerning Table 1-16 MPLAB XC16 Compiler Users Guide there is no "m" constraint but "d", "g" and some others.

Comment: Did you try "+m"?  If this compiler is based on gcc, it may still work.  Maybe the docs are wrong?

Comment: Yes I tried "+m". The compiler produced something, but unfortunately produces invalid instructions.

Comment: So, looking thru the Programmer's Reference manual (where the instruction set for xc16 is defined), the `btsts.c` instruction doesn't seem to support a memory address as a parameter, only a register (indeed, I don't think any of their instructions supports this).  The specifics of the instruction set varies by processor (and you didn't specify yours) so ymmv, but I'm guessing this is inherent to the entire chipset.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Indeed, BTSTS.C can not handle memory, but BTSTS can. However the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this then?

```
unsigned short a __at((0x100)) = 1;

int main()
{
   asm (
       "btsts %0, #2\n"
       : "+m" (a)
   );
   return a;
}
```

Build with xc16-gcc -mcci -O1 -mcpu=30F4011 -S m.c

```
_main:
        .set ___PA___,0
        btsts   _a, #2

        mov     _a,w0
        return
```

Comment: While this seems to work on the first place if called with global variable directly it will not work if a is an method argument like in `volatile unsigned int r = 0;
void test(volatile unsigned int* t) {
    asm (
       "btsts %0, #2\n"
       : "+m" (t)
   );
}` This will produce uncorrect code like `mov #_r,w0 mov w0,[w14] btsts [w14], #2`